# MySQL query for wordpress day events

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm a WordPress (PHP) developer, however I have not done a lot of complex MySQL queries. I am working on an events website and want to create filters: User should be able to filter events by the following criteria: TODAY, TOMORROW, THIS WEEKEND, NEXT 7 DAYS, CHOOSE YOUR DATES.

Meta data used to filter events is below and can be found in the post meta db table in the meta_key column.

```
start_date
end_date
times
recurring_event
days
sold_out
cancelled
```

This is how the table looks like:

```
id post_id  meta_key         meta_value
1   12      start_date       20140923
2   22      days             a:4:{i:0;s:6:"monday";i:1;s:9:"wednesday";i:2;s:6:"friday";i:3;s:8:"saturday"}           
3   12      end_date         20141003
4   78      recurring_event  0
5   34      times            24 Hours
6   12      days             a:2:{i:0;s:6:"monday";i:1;s:7:"tuesday";}
7   67      start_date       20140906
8   45      end_date         20141108
```

What MySQL queries can I use to get events for Today, Tomorrow, Weekend and 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know SQL enough, then, for this case, I would caculate the date with PHP and then make the query with SQL.

These are the pages that helped me for the following :

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mktime.php

1) For today, no calculation, just get the date of today and make the query :

```
<?php
$today = date('Y-m-d',mktime());
$result = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE start_date = "'.$today.'"');
?>
```

2) Tomorow, calculate tomorow date :

```
<?php
$tomorow = date('Y-m-d',mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y")));
$result = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE start_date = "'.$tomorow.'"');
?>
```

3) 7 days later, calculate 7 days later date :

```
<?php
$day7 = date('Y-m-d',mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+7, date("Y")));
$result = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE start_date = "'.$day7.'"');
?>
```

3) Week end, calculte when week end comes :
For this one, I cannot write it so quickly, sorry.

Explanations :

date('Y-m-d',mktime()); gives 2014-09-04 in $today.

Because mktime() is empty, so mktime() is based on the server time, no argument.

Y => year like ####

m => month like ##

d => day like ##

date('Y-m-d',mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"))); gives 2014-09-05

This time we gave arguments to mktime(), 0 hour, 0 minutes, 0 second, 09, 04+1, 2014.

date("m") = 09

date("d")+1 = 04+1 = 05

date("Y") = 2014

I hope this might help you.
I'm sorry, but I don't know how put PHP in Wordpress.
Nils.

Comment: Zod answer is much better !

Answer (score 0):

For the weekend and next 7 days you may have to mix sql and php

Today

```
 SELECT * from  tablename where start_date=CURDATE();
```

Tomorrow

```
 SELECT * from  tablename where start_date = CURDATE()+INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

For Weekend  you have to find the weekend dates first.

using

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK
```

you can find current day . So if you have an array , match with it and 
add how many  days to reach Saturday and sunday.
I dont know any other easy way

For next 7 days

```
 SELECT * from  tablename where start_date >= CURDATE() and 
start_date=< CURDATE()+INTERVAL 7 DAY;
```

Use the tutorial and try yourself :-)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate

Comment: Zod, thanks, I refined the query to SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE meta_key = 'start_date' = CURDATE(), and it is successful but brings zero results when I query using phpMyadmin, is there something that I need to add?

Comment: is start_date a table field ?  if meta_key is the field name what kind of db structure is that ?  if meta_key is the field name  you can try this way WHERE meta_key = 'start_date' and meta_value=date_format(curdate(), '%Y/%m/%d')

Comment: This is a wordpress database and the table is post_meta, so start_date, end_date, days and time are under the meta_key row as illustrated above in my question. Not sure if the date format is a problem as wordpress event date save as text with a format such as this 20140923, not sure if the format is th problem?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date